# HTML Background Image Link

Tags: html, css, image

Can anyone help me with this one please,

What i want is a link with a background image, positioned in a row inside a table.

Appreciate the help
thanks

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Is JavaScript allowed?

Comment: "in a row inside a table". Ahh.. I can see the table in front of me. (please show the relevant HTML)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    a  
    {
        background-image:url('http://www.google.com/logos/2011/mary_blair-2011-hp.jpg');
    }
    table, td, th
    {
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a  href=”www.google.com”> Google</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            Google
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any element can have a background image:

```
<a href='link' style='background-image:url("/images/link.png");'>link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your link or `<a>` tag the style `display:block` and give it a specific width and height it should work just fine.

```
a.classname {
    display:block;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    background: url(images/myImage.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <a href="your_link_target.htm">
             <img src="image_path.jpg" alt="This is a test image link">
          </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```